# Möbius transformation of nonconcentric circles

Tags: transformation, conformal-geometry

Is there any transformation that can match two circles with equal radii (say $r_0$) which are positioned at $(0,0)$ and $(X_0, Y_0)$  to two concentric circles? I know there is a transformation when  $Y_0$ is equal to zero, but I need both $X_0$ and $Y_0$ to be nonzero. The initial circles do not collide which means $X_0^2+Y_0^2>>4 r_0^2$. I should also note that I don't like to use rotation to make $Y_0$ equal to zero because my boundary condition is difficult. What is the transformation that can do the job?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking about moving one or both circles so that they coincide? If you can do what you want when both circles are on the $x$-axis you can start by rotating the whole plane to put the second one there. Please [edit] the question to clarify (don't just reply in a commnet). A picture might help us. So would knowing why you want to know.

Comment: I edited my question. I think it is different from the mentioned question in the comment because I am asking: what is the transformation?